# Функция array_splice

Tags: php, массивы

для программирования новый и извините если вопрос глупый , есть массив с ключами вместо индексов (словарь) и функция `$book=array_splice($bookList,0,1)[0]` ноль в конце означает что вырезанный массив стает на нулевой индекс в массиве '$book' ? Не могу найти информации по этому вопросу , заранее благодарен)

Comment: функция вам возвращает массив, `[0]` в конце это доступ по индексу к нулевому элементу результирующего массива.

Comment: `[0]` - означает первый элемент, т.е. `$book` будет присвоено первый элемент из массива `$bookList` (обрезанного)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-splice.php

Comment: `array_shift($bookList)` приведет ровно к тому же результату

Comment: @entithat первый из отрезанной части.

Comment: @teran, я так и сказал с:

Comment: @entithat _"обрезанный массив `$booklist`"_ это скорее оставшаяся часть исходного,  а не тот первый элемент, который отрезан от него.

Comment: @teran, это уже игра слов.. Смысл остался тот же.

Answer (score 0):

> `[0]` - означает первый элемент, т.е. $book будет присвоено первый элемент из массива $bookList (обрезанного) - @entithat
>
> `array_shift($bookList)` приведет ровно к тому же результату - @teran

Спасибо)